# Dynamically generate multiple less files from less template and database variables

Tags: c#, xslt, less

I have a less file template with some varables at the top. We are bringing on 500 new clients so I need to generate 500 new less files from the colors that each client is going to give me. These colors will be stored in a database. I tried to accomplish this with an xslt template but all the & keep coming out as &amp; and is breaking the less. This is what I have so far

```
 //loop through each row of colors
 XmlElement elem = doc.GetElementFromRow(row);
 var xslTran = new XslTransform();
 xslTran.Load(filePathToXslt);
 var fileName = String.Format("theme_{0}.less", row["Name"]);
 var writer = new XmlTextWriter(mappedPath, Encoding.UTF8);
 xslTran.Transform(elem, null, writer);
```

Less looks something like this.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:template match="/NewDataSet">
//variables
@color_link:#<xsl:value-of select="Table/Color3" />; // secondary1
@color_link_hover:#<xsl:value-of select="Table/Color2" />; // Secondary1 hover

#profileTabs {
  .tab {    
    <![CDATA[&#explore-tab:hover {]]>
      .h-type5 {
       h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
        background-color: @color_link;
       }
     } 
    }
}
</xsl:template></xsl:stylesheet>
```

Im looking for a solution to this or if there is a beter way to do it without using xslt please let me know.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does SQL have to do with this?

Comment: The variables are coming from database, but I guess your right. It doesn't have anything to do with answering the question. Ill remove the tag

Comment: And how is this less file used? I mean do you really need to generate these 500 new less files? Can't you just set the variable values when the less template is converted to CSS (e.g. with compiler options or programmatically, yet again depending on the way the template is used)?

Comment: Normally we pre-compile all all less templates and just have the css file on the server so its really fast. I could not think of a way to have it change colors on the fly. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS and less are no XML formats, so XSLT might not be <strike>the droids you are looking for</strike> the best tool. I found [Mustache](http://mustache.github.io/) quite suitable for such a task. It does have a C# implementation available. Your input file would look something like:

```
   @color_link:#{{color3}}; // secondary1
   @color_link_hover:#{{color2}} />; // Secondary1 hover
```

and you would supply a map with the stuff in double curly braces as keys.

Let us know how it goes.

Comment: Interesting, Ill look into that now. Thanks

Comment: Do you know, is it possible to use this and generate a new css file that I can then put on my server?

Comment: Mustache isn't a LESS compiler :-), but if your less only contains variables (and not mixins and other advanced stuff) I see no reason you couldn't write CSS directly. Feel free to accept the answer